# Change of Button Color on Click until I click again in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create an Android App in which I want to change my button color when I clicked and that color should be change until I press again.

For Example

On first click color should be red and on click again it should converts to green,  it should remain red until I click again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default it will be grey but after click on button it will change to orage until press any other button it will remain same (orange)
Create two colors resource files in drawable and use them as background like I did. And then use this code in OnClick of button.

```
            homeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray);
            settingButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_orange);
            isPressed = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a switch by getting the color. Put in your `OnClickListener` something like

```
if(button.getBackgroundColor == COLOR.RED)
    button.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.GREEN);
else
    button.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can do like this using flag to keep track of color

```
var flag=false 

btn.setOnClickListener{
     flag=!flag
     if(flag)
        it.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
     else
        it.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    }
```